# Lists reassigning each other without specifying to change them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to create a program that will take in multiple scores for pizza. I then need to remove the highest and lowest value in the list to remove outliers. However when I try to remove the highest and lowest score, it removes the highest and lowest score from the oldScores list

```
pizzaScores = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
oldPizzaScores = pizzaScores
for i in range(len(pizzaScores)):
    pizzaScores[i].remove(max(pizzaScores[i]))
    pizzaScores[i].remove(min(pizzaScores[i]))
print(oldPizzaScores)
print(pizzaScores)
```

Comment: `oldPizzaScores` should be a copy, not reference to `pizzaScores`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening as you're just assigning object `oldPizzaScores = pizzaScores` and values are not getting copied here. You can use deepcopy to copy values like `oldPizzaScores = deepcopy(pizzaScores)`

Use deep copy instead.

```
from copy import deepcopy
pizzaScores = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
oldPizzaScores = deepcopy(pizzaScores)
for i in range(len(pizzaScores)):
    pizzaScores[i].remove(max(pizzaScores[i]))
    pizzaScores[i].remove(min(pizzaScores[i]))
print(oldPizzaScores)
print(pizzaScores)
```

**Output:**

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

[[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]

Answer (score 0):

I went through [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891076/difference-between-list-definitions-in-python) some time ago

The line `oldPizzaScores = pizzaScores` is the real culprit. It is assigning the reference of `pizzaScores` variable to `oldPizzaScores`.
So any change you make to `pizzaScores` will be applied to <strike>the other list also</strike> the original list, which you have referred in that line.

To avoid this issue, you should use `deepcopy` method from `copy` library

change the line `oldPizzaScores = pizzaScores` to `oldPizzaScores = deepcopy(pizzaScores)`

```
from copy import deepcopy
pizzaScores = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
oldPizzaScores = deepcopy(pizzaScores)
for i in range(len(pizzaScores)):
    pizzaScores[i].remove(max(pizzaScores[i]))
    pizzaScores[i].remove(min(pizzaScores[i]))
print(oldPizzaScores)
print(pizzaScores)
```

**P.S.**

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide, it would be amazing if you use variable names with lowercase separated by `_`

For example, `oldPizzaScores` should be renamed to `old_pizza_scores` and so on!

Comment: "So any change you make to pizzaScores will be applied to the other list also." => actually the point is that there is __no__ "other list" here - both names are refering to the very same list.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I agree. I will rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

```
pizzaScores = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
oldPizzaScores = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
for i in range(len(pizzaScores)):
    pizzaScores[i].remove(max(pizzaScores[i]))
    pizzaScores[i].remove(min(pizzaScores[i]))
print(oldPizzaScores)
print(pizzaScores)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code,
the 2nd line is where the bug lies.

```
oldPizzaScores = pizzaScores
```

This line makes a new reference (oldPizzaScores) points to value (which is also pointed by pizzaScores). That implies -

```
1. If you change oldPizzaScores then pizzaScores will also change accordingly. For eg,
    >>> oldPizzaScores.pop() // remove the last item
    >>> oldPizzaScores
    >>> pizzaScores   // same valua as above

2. Similar as point 1 with pizzaScores.
```

The solution -

```
Do a deep copy of pizzaScores such that the values are copied to oldPizzaScores, i.e.
    from copy import deepcopy
    oldPizzaScores = deepcopy(pizzaScores)
```

You can also use slice operator instead of deepcopy module. Do as -

```
    oldPizzaScores = pizzaScores[:]
```